# REGEXREPLACE in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I am trying to use REGEX in Google Sheets to clean up form data arriving as comma delimited data with arbitrary leading commas and single spaces.

sample data from form:

> ,,Refrigerator,,,,, ,,Slide,,Dual Slide,,Microwave Oven,,Indoor Shower,Built in Stereo,Day/Night Switch,,BluRay/DVD

I want to use

```
REGEXREPLACE(text, regular_expression, replacement)
```

to remove multiple commas and single spaces that may occur between commas, replacing with a single comma so the line reads

> Refrigerator,Slide,Dual Slide,Microwave Oven,   . . . etc

The match string `(^,+|(,+ ,)|,+)` [works properly in the Rubular.com simulator](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/96644/02a998f4e2c78326efba4ec9a305e7cc), but when used in the Google Spreadsheet as in example with raw data above pasted in at cell M12 as source text:

```
REGEXREPLACE("M12","(^,+|(,+ ,)|,+)",",")
```

it fails by not removing one of the leading commas.

> ,Refrigerator,,,,, ,,Slide,,Dual Slide,,Microwave Oven,,Indoor Shower,Built in Stereo,Day/Night Switch,,BluRay/DVD

The Googlesheet REGEX help points to https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt which seems to describe the operations the same as the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

From what you're describing, Google is working as expected and the other site linked isn't. Your regex is matching `^,+`, amongst other things, (ie one or more commas at the start), and replacing them with a single comma.  If the input string has commas at the start, I would expect the output to have one too.

You could build on what you've done with another regular expression replace, and strip any leading commas:

```
REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(M12,"((,+ ,)|,+)",","), "^,+", "")
```

This uses your original one, minus the leading commas part, to do the original replace, then wraps it in a second call looking for *just* leading commas, and replacing those with nothing.

Having said that, your original regex is also not quite working as expected either and isn't stripping all the commas and spaces down to a single comma in all circumstances.  Instead, you can use this one:

```
REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(M12,"( ?(, *)+)",","), "^,+", "")
```

This looks for an optional space, followed by one or more commas, each with zero or more commas after them, replacing the whole lot with a single comma, then keeping the new "remove all commas at the start" replace also.

Comment: Perhaps also `=REGEXREPLACE(M12,"(^|,)[, ]+","$1")`

Comment: @AdamL yes that would work for the OPs example.  While testing I covered off extra spaces before/after the values as well too though, just in case!

Comment: James, Adam: Thanks very much for the comments and detailed explanation - trying to learn some new tricks at age 66  but I am like kid playing with razor blades . Good to see how professional programmers think beyond the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

One more good way to do this:

`=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,SPLIT(A1,", "))`